# Swiching between different perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

What is the difference between 'Java Perspective', 'J2EE Perspective' and 'JPA Perspective' in Eclipse ?

Will it hamper anything to the code if i switch between perspectives?

Thanks,
Sudhansu.

Comment: The perspective in eclipse controls the default views that you see.  It will not hamper anything if and when you switch between perspectives.  Also, any view that is available in any perspective is available in all other perspectives; however, some views do not make sence in some perspectives (for example, the javaDoc view in a C-language perspective.

Answer (score 1):

"A perspective is a visual container for a set of views and editors (parts)" [eclipse.org/.../PerspectiveArticle.html](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html%20%22eclipse.org./.../%22PerspectiveArticle.html)

As an example, in the "J2EE Perspective" is the "Server"-view already added. This view does not make any sense at "Java Perspective".

So perspecitves (and views, editors) are only about the User-Interface. The perspectives do not have any effect on the code.

Answer (score 0):

No changes in code result if you switch between perspectives which are layouts in Eclipse

Check out these links

1. Eclipse - Perspectives(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_perspectives.htm),
2. Java Perspectives(http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-perspective.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A perspective in Eclipse is the way it will show you code and tools. Every perspective is made for an individual workflow. "Java" e.g. is for simple coding in Java and focusses on the Code in the middle. "Debug" e.g. perspective does not focus on the code but instead shows you tools which help you to analyze you actual problem (Thread Monitor, Variable Monitor etc.)